# Set rdlc report a4 page height of tablix to fill remaining height of the page based on row size

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am designing an invoice in RDLC report. In the body part I have a table which contains Name, Price, Quantity and Amount columns. This table also contains a footer row that displays some totals. Below the table is summary section that contains total invoice amount and few other details.

The summary section is just about 1.5 inch height in A4 size page. I want that the summary section stick at the bottom of the A4 sized page and the items table fill the remaining height of the page. I also want that footer row in items table is just above the summary section. In short, the table's (tablix in terms of RDLC) body must fill the height of the page.

Sample Rdlc Print file:[image]

[Out Put to be needed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJO7n.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a sample desired output? It would help us determine what needs to be changed in your current RDLC.

Comment: Added output what am looking for@JohnEphraimTugado